# Como calcular timestamp no SQL

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um Campo (status) INT no banco, tenho um script que atualiza ele a cada 5 minutos usando time() do php.

Como faço para calcular via sql?

Segue o select que estou usando.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 0):

não sei qual o SGBD que você utiliza eu trabalho bastante com SQLServer 2014 e para realizar esse procedimento de intevalo realizo da seguinte forma

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status >= CAST((convert(datetime,getdate(),108)) + '00:10:00.000' as time(7))
```

Comment: eu uso o mysqli com php